# I can't understand this result

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%d\t", 1);
   write(1, "Acorn\n", 6);
   printf("%d\t", 2);
   write(1, "Book\n", 5);

   return 0;
}
```

I want to get the result below.

```
1   Acorn

2   Book
```

But above code's result is below.

```
Acorn

Book

1        2
```

I can't solve this problem. I thought hard about this.

What should I do to make the code which can print first result?

Comment: `printf("1 Acorn\n2 Book");`

Comment: I must use the system function. "write".

Comment: `write(1, "1 Acorn\n2 Book", 14);`

Comment: Hmm.. I mean, if when I want to print number that I must use printf

Comment: but if when I want to print string that I muse use write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stdio`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3//stdio.3.html) is buffered. You need to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before each call to `write(1,` ... (since it is a [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)), or else end each `printf` format string with a `\n`  (since *stdout* is generally *line-buffered*).

BTW, you could fill a string buffer using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) then later [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) it. See also [fdopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) & [dprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dprintf.3.html) & [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) & [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) ...

Answer (score 1):

The output of `printf` is stuck in the output buffer. In order to interoperate with `write`, you'll need to flush:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%d\t", 1);
   fflush(stdout);
   write(1, "Acorn\n", 6);
   printf("%d\t", 2);
   fflush(stdout);
   write(1, "Book\n", 5);

   return 0;
}
```